# How to adjust a customized function to get the difference between years?

Tags: r, function, date

I am trying to define a customized function to get the difference in years between two dates,

Here's what I got so far:

```
library(lubridate)

## function to get the difference between years ##
set_dif_years <- function(end_date, start_date){
  return(lubridate :: year(end_date)- lubridate :: year(start_date))
}

## testing function ##
set_dif_years(end_date=format(as.Date('01/08/2019', format='%d/%m/%Y'), "%d/%m/%Y"),
               start_date=format(as.Date('28/08/2019', format='%d/%m/%Y'), "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Console output:

```
# -27
```

For this case expected function output should be `0`.
However I can't figure out what is missing in the function,

Is there any way to adjust the function in order to get desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get illogical results, look at all intermediate objects.

```r
format(as.Date('01/08/2019', format='%d/%m/%Y'), "%d/%m/%Y")
# [1] "01/08/2019"
lubridate::year(format(as.Date('01/08/2019', format='%d/%m/%Y'), "%d/%m/%Y"))
# [1] 1
```

Does that make sense? Let's look at the other one.

```r
format(as.Date('28/08/2019', format='%d/%m/%Y'), "%d/%m/%Y")
# [1] "28/08/2019"
lubridate::year(format(as.Date('28/08/2019', format='%d/%m/%Y'), "%d/%m/%Y"))
# [1] 28
```

This is because you `lubridate::year` is using `as.POSIXlt`, with no candidate date formats, which thinks that the first number is the year. (Don't confuse human-eyes-obvious with machine-obvious/unambiguous.)

```r
as.POSIXlt(format(as.Date('01/08/2019', format='%d/%m/%Y'), "%d/%m/%Y"))
# [1] "0001-08-20 LMT"

as.POSIXlt(format(as.Date('28/08/2019', format='%d/%m/%Y'), "%d/%m/%Y"))
# [1] "0028-08-20 LMT"
```

---

Fixes:

- don't go back and forth and back again between `Date` and `Class`; if you want to do year-arithmetic, just convert to the `Date` class and stick with it

  ```r
  set_dif_years(end_date=as.Date('01/08/2019', format='%d/%m/%Y'),
                start_date=as.Date('28/08/2019', format='%d/%m/%Y'))
  ```
- if you must use `character`, however, since `year` does not accept `format=` that most date/datetime functions allow, you need to make it an unambiguous string up-front:

  ```r
  set_dif_years(end_date=format(as.Date('01/08/2019', format='%d/%m/%Y'), "%Y/%m/%d"),
                start_date=format(as.Date('28/08/2019', format='%d/%m/%Y'), "%Y/%m/%d"))
  ```